# Test if browser have internet connection using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, internet-connection

Is there any new HTML5 API, I couldn't find anything, that will check if user have internet connection. Or maybe there is unusual use of some API that will allow to do this. I had to test it and I've used ajax call to test, is there other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some new browsers there is the `navigator.onLine` property and the `online` and `offline` events.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine

Failing that, you could try an `Image` element instead of AJAX (assuming you can find a consistent image URL that won't disappear).  This has the advantage of not needing to worry about cross-origin security limitations that make it hard to distinguish a failed AJAX call from one that was blocked because of CORS issues.